# Bootstrap - Full carousel as control

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make an entire carousel act as the "next" control?

I have a minimal carousel without controls:

```
  <div id="sld" class="carousel paper2 slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active" id="first">
        <img src="img/01.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="second">
        <img src="img/02.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="last">
        <img src="img/03.jpg>
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you want only the NEXT button, without the the Previous one?

Comment: Yes, only NEXT. Thanks @Walucas. Bellow is the answer. many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zru5qqv5/)**

You have a method called **[`.carousel('next')`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carouselnext)** which you can call/attach it to `.carousel`'s `click` event as below:

```
$('.carousel').on('click',function(){
    $(this).carousel('next');
});
```

so this will move to **`next image`** whenever/wherever you `click` on your `carousel`

---

**Here is the Snippet DEMO**

```js
$('.carousel').on('click',function(){
    $(this).carousel('next');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="sld" class="carousel paper2 slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active" id="first">
        <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-N2fSe2JF0rg/T-vAeJcx4tI/AAAAAAAAErU/bOy8ya936xA/s1600/Tiger+3D+Wallpapers.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="second">
        <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CMIQjovvgcQ/VOy4zOpkW3I/AAAAAAAAAH4/8cE_5moqRFQ/s1600/happy%2Bholi%2Bphotos.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="last">
        <img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-45891755,width-640,resizemode-4/nasas-images-of-most-remarkable-events-you-cant-miss.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's perfect @Guruprasad Rao. Many, many thanks. Sorry for the delay.: I got sick :P

Comment: No probs.. Happy coding.. :)